# How to remove local storage data after uninstallation of the application from Android

Tags: android, html, cordova, local-storage

I made an application which stores data in local storage and use that data even after restarting the application. But it stores the data even after uninstalling the application.

So is there any way to remove that local storage data after uninstalling the application.

Comment: How are you storing them ? as external files ?

Comment: "But it stores the data even after uninstalling the application"    Are you sure that your app works even after uninstalling it?

Comment: where are you store data wich types ?

Comment: "But it stores the data even after uninstalling the application" -- you are welcome to publish a project that provides proof of this claim. `WebView`, the Android component at the heart of PhoneGap, should put HTML5 local storage on Android's internal storage, and internal storage is deleted when the app is uninstalled.

Comment: I using HTML5 local storage like this localStorage.name="Sourav"; which stores the name even after uninstalling the application.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code to detect old app version in a manual manner:

```
/*your current app version, you should manually update it here*/
var Appversion = "1.2"; 
var savedAppVersion = localStorage.getItem("version");
/*if there is one check if it is the same*/
if (savedAppVersion && savedAppVersion === version)
{ // do nothing }
else {
/*clear local storage*/
localStorage.clear();
/*save new app version*/
localStorage.setItem("version", version);
}
```

Otherwise you can use `$cordovaAppVersion.getVersionNumber()` methode to get actual app version

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

if you are using sqlite data base to store data it will remove with your application remove,also related sharedprefrence data will remove, but if you store on external storage with specific folder files it will not remove with your Application unistall.